# How to define Multiple occurrences in XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, xsd, fedex

I am trying to integrate FedEx in my application . In one module i had to define one element as Multiple occurrences. please check below image
[image]

How i need to define EVENTS element ? 
I tried below methods

```
1
<ON_DELIVER type="EVENTS"/>
2
<EVENTS>ON_DELIVER</EVENTS>
3
<EVENTS>[ON_DELIVER]</EVENTS>
4
<EVENTS>
  <ON_DELIVER>TRUE</ON_DELIVER>
</EVENTS>
```

I got below error `Element 'Events' is a simple type, so it must have no element information item [children]`
I want to know how can i define EVENTS element with that 5 values.

Answer (score 0):

The below XML should help you setup multiple notifications.
One for the customer and one for your customer service team

```
<SpecialServicesRequested>
    <SpecialServiceTypes>EVENT_NOTIFICATION</SpecialServiceTypes>
    <EventNotificationDetail>
        <AggregationType>PER_SHIPMENT</AggregationType>
        <PersonalMessage>This is a notification sent by Fedex, for your order: XXXX-XXXX</PersonalMessage>
        <EventNotifications>
            <Role>RECIPIENT</Role>
            <Events>ON_SHIPMENT</Events>
            <Events>ON_EXCEPTION</Events>
            <Events>ON_ESTIMATED_DELIVERY</Events>
            <Events>ON_DELIVERY</Events>
            <NotificationDetail>
                <NotificationType>EMAIL</NotificationType>
                <EmailDetail>
                    <EmailAddress>XXXX@hotmail.com</EmailAddress>
                    <Name>Claire Pounder</Name>
                </EmailDetail>
                <Localization>
                    <LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
                </Localization>
            </NotificationDetail>
            <FormatSpecification>
                <Type>HTML</Type>
            </FormatSpecification>
        </EventNotifications>
        <EventNotifications>
            <Role>SHIPPER</Role>
            <Events>ON_SHIPMENT</Events>
            <Events>ON_EXCEPTION</Events>
            <Events>ON_ESTIMATED_DELIVERY</Events>
            <Events>ON_DELIVERY</Events>
            <NotificationDetail>
                <NotificationType>EMAIL</NotificationType>
                <EmailDetail>
                    <EmailAddress>XXXX@YOUREMAIL.com</EmailAddress>
                    <Name>MANAGER Email</Name>
                </EmailDetail>
                <Localization>
                    <LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
                </Localization>
            </NotificationDetail>
            <FormatSpecification>
                <Type>HTML</Type>
            </FormatSpecification>
        </EventNotifications>
    </EventNotificationDetail>
</SpecialServicesRequested>
```

Comment: That XML is taken from a live request that books 100s of consignments a day. It works, if you want to include your XML people can have a look